# How to deal with unbalanced xgboost multiclass classification within Scikit.learn pipeline?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

I am using XGBClassifier to model an unbalanced multiclass target. I have a few questions:

```
First I would like to now where should I use the parameter weight on the instantion of the classifier or on the fit step of the pipeline?

Second question is how I calculate a weights. I assume that the sum of the array should be 1.

Third: Is there any order of the weight array that maps the diferent label classes?
```

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question:

> where should I use the parameter weight

Use `sample_weight` in `XGBClassifier.fit()`

```
xgb_clf = xgb.XGBClassifier()
xgb_clf.fit(X, y, sample_weight=sample_weight)
```

When using `pipeline`:

```
pipe = Pipeline([
    ('my_xgb_clf', xgb.XGBClassifier()),
])
pipe.fit(X, y, my_xgb_clf__sample_weight=sample_weight)
```

Btw, some API in sklearn does not support `sample_weight` kwarg, e.g., `learning_curve`.

So I simply do this:

```
import functools
xgb_clf.fit = functools.partial(xgb_clf.fit, sample_weight=sample_weight)
```

*Note*: You would need to patch `fit()` again after a grid search, because `GridSearchCV.best_estimator_` will not be the original estimator.

---

For the second question:

> how I calculate a weights. I assume that the sum of the array should be 1.

```
from sklearn.utils import compute_sample_weight
sample_weight = compute_sample_weight('balanced', y_train)
```

This simulates `class_weight='balanced'` in sklearn.

Note:

- Sum of the array is not 1. You can normalize it, but I think the
  score result would be different.
- This does not equal to `class_weight='balanced_subsample'`
  I can not find a way to simulate this.

---

For the third question:

> Is there any order...

Sorry I don't understand what you mean...

Maybe you want the order in `xgb_clf.classes_`?
You can access this after calling `xgb_clf.fit`.
Or just use `np.unique(y_train)`.

Comment: About the answer to the first question: when I use
```pipe.fit(X, y, my_xgb_clf__sample_weight=sample_weight)``` my kernel dies...

when I use

```xgb_clf.fit = functools.partial(xgb_clf.fit, sample_weight=sample_weight)```

I got the following error:

```NotFittedError: This ColumnTransformer instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method.```

Comment: @Hugo This error was for `ColumnTransformer`.  `ColumnTransformer.transform()` was called somewhere before `ColumnTransformer.fit()`. How did you use it?

Comment: `preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('num', numeric_transformer, numeric_features),
        ('cat', categorical_transformer, categorical_features),
    ])

clf = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('preprocessor', preprocessor),
    ('classifier', XGBClassifier())
])`

Comment: @Hugo [This](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_column_transformer_mixed_types.html) example works fine on my machine (Python 3.7 & sklearn 0.21.2) with changing the last line to `clf.fit(X_train, y_train, classifier__sample_weight=sample_weight)`. I can not reproduce the error.

Comment: Thanks. Probably another kind of bug. I am trying to find if it is related with Scikit-Learn